# Angular not working after deploying to IIS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-8

I created an MVC application - nothing complex.  I then added angularjs to the index page - with one module and access to web api.  Everything works perfect, until I decide to deploy to IIS.  All the angularjs stuff don't work.  The {{...}} shows up literally.  I use chrome dev tools -> console.  I do not see any errors on loading any files.

I decided to create a basic app - MVC but with just the index page.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div ng-app="">
    <h1>Hello {{ "Geoff" }}</h1>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
}
```

I added angular to the application and to the index page.  I works just fine in visual studio.  When I deploy - using visual studio - and browse to the new website, the page displays but with Hello {{ "Geoff" }} instead of Hello Geoff.  No Errors in chrome->dev tools.

I will absolutely appreciate help on this.  I am tired looking everywhere on the net and not find any solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While it can be frustrating to "look everywhere on the net" and not find an answer to your question, this is not an issue that is reproducible the way you have presented it.  It's not clear what you searched for, or how your IIS server is configured.  There is definitely not an incompatibility between these two software libraries, it *must* be your configuration.

Comment: I can't comment on IIS but I'll try to help with Angular. Have you declared your Angular app like this: `angular.module("App");` and tried putting the name of that app in the attribute `ng-app="App"`?

Comment: to start with, whenever angular displays `{{ }}` it is an indication that the library did not load.  You stated that you have no console errors, but this seems unlikely.  At first glance, this seems like it could be an issue with the location of the `/Scripts` folder location on the IIS server.

Comment: my vote for closure as off topic due to not having a [mcve] is not an indication that I am not interested in helping, but an indication that the question isn't answerable definitively with the information you have provided.

Comment: Ok. I am sorry if I did not make my problem clear.  Let me try again. Here are the steps to what I did (exactly)

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to write a long series of comments trying to describe step by step your process.  Even if you listed every step, and someone were to follow step by step, there is still no guarantee that they would achieve the same result;  The best that might occur is that they would be able to identify the error that you aren't identifying in the question body.  While we really do want to help here, this kind of remote troubleshooting just isn't a good fit for this site format.  If you need guided troubleshooting assistance, using a chat room is a much better option.

Comment: sorry if I did not make my problem clear.  Steps 1) create an MVC application using visual studio template for that. 2) added the Angular library to the application.

Comment: This is the first time, I am posting a problem - I have used the site for help several times.  If you can help me with were i should go, I will appreciate

Comment: as I suspected, the steps you provided are not enough to reproduce the issue.  I was able to create an MVC application, add your exact code, upload to both a local IIS server and a remote IIS server, and the code displayed correctly in both instances.  This *strongly* points to a configuration issue in your IIS, but there isn't any information here that would even begin to shed any light on what that configuration issue might be.  Again, it seems *very* unlikely that you have no console errors.

Answer (score -1):

[image]When publishing a Visual Studio project, in the settings step of the publishing wizard, you are prompted with 2 options, a release configuration (default) or debug. Choosing Release will minify all your script which can lead to a broken angular reference.
Try to publish your project with the debug option.

Comment: "Try to publish your project with the debug option. " ... that is not publishing then :)

Comment: Its in the publishing configuration options, so it is publishing. Furthermore, this will allow him to determine whether minification is an issue or not.